# datepicker wont start after ajax div reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker inside a div that is updated via ajax. I'm able to open datepicker once after whole page reloads, but after ajax updates only a div that includes datepicker input, I'm not able to see datepicker. I have tried a solutions that I wound for similar problems, with no luck.

I'm not very familiar with jquery and ajax, so maybe someone can see the problem immediatly.

I have a jquery function that includes ajax:

```
function example(){
$.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  cache: false, 
  success: function(data){
    $('#div').html(data);
  }
});

}
```

Ajax reloads a div, which has a datepicker input inside,
which looks like this  :

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Datepicker is constructed this way:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"});
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
        $.extend(
            {'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd'},
            $.datepicker.regional['fi']
        )
    );
});
```

What do I have to do, to be able to see datepicker every time div updates via ajax?
Some suggested datepicker to be refresh at ajax success, I didnt get it working this way, or didnt know how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to rerun the `.datepicker()` initializer on ajax success.

Change the datepicker code to:

```
function applyDatepicker(elem) {
    $(elem).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"});
    //... Your datepicker code
}
```

Then once on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    applyDatepicker('#datepicker');
})
```

And once in your ajax success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    //... other ajax params,
    success: function(){
        //... success callback code
        applyDatepicker('#datepicker');
    }
});
```

Also, as [@adrenalin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965668/476786) suggests, the only way to figure the best practice would be to know more about your code.

---

A suggestion would be to change the element to have a `class="datepicker"` rather than an `id` for the main reason that there could be multiple datepickers in a page and id's are always meant to be unique. As a beginner, I suggest the easiest approach is to try to imagine an ID as an element's Proper Noun whereas Class will be it's Common Noun or Adjective!

Comment: datepicker initializer is now located in page.php (inside a page that ajax is calling). That was anly place i could get it working. Should it be at same page that ajax jquery is to get it working your way?

Comment: By working I meant working when whole page is reloaded. I tried the way you told me but then I couldnt start datepicker even when whole page was reloaded.

Comment: You add all of the above in the main page. This is the page that makes the ajax call, not the one that is loaded/called via ajax. Not knowing anything about your actual code, all I can suggest is that it will most likely go in the same page as where you have the code that does the ajax call.

Comment: Thank you very much! After adding all scripts to main page and deleting extra ')' from my code, its working now :), just to way you told. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker would need to be initialized as the one you loaded with AJAX is completely new element and was not there when you initialized it in the first place. None of the original events are bound to the new element anymore. Do it on the AJAX load success callback (which depends on the way you are doing it.

It really depends on how the code is constructed to tell what the best practise would be, but if you load the content in general in one place only, either repeat the datepicker initialization or wrap it in a function and call it wherever it is needed.