# Datepicker only life once based ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have implemented ajax request to load a main content in  page. You know, like master page.
The structured like this :

```
<head></head>
<body>
   <navbar> Like -Home-, -Contact- , -About- , -Login-  </navbar>
   <div id='main-content'>

   </div>

   /*This is for javascript*/
   <script src='jquery.js'> </script>
   <script src='jquery-ui.js'> </script>           
</body>
```

For Example, when user click on Contact menu in navbar, ajax call the contact.html and reload the page on id='main-content'.

> My question is, If I use javascript like jquery-ui which is in this case I use datetime based jquery-ui, It just load once. Just say, on Home, there is a datetime for input form  and that working, then I go to contact page. when I back again to home page, the datetime is not work. It just like a common text ? Any idea it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinitializing the datepicker when its page is opened like this:

```
$('#yourdatepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your navigation is based on ajax and every time you navigate to new page you get fresh DOM without refereshing page your js load just when you open your site for the first time and it will init the component loaded in document, that why you find that *on Home, there is a datetime for input form and that working*.

So you have to reinitializing your components after ajax call, example :

```
$("input[name=datepicker]").datepicker({arguments});
```

Take a look to [datepicker wont start after ajax div reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965561/datepicker-wont-start-after-ajax-div-reload).

Hopr this helps.